# Whats the cleanest way to change $http base url?

Tags: angularjs

Im looking to hit a separate http server I have running using, Angular $http service.  How can I change the base url without using $location? 
Right now it points to 9000 and for calls I want to change it to 3000.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using NodeJs's grunt or gulp (which you should be) use connectmod rewrite

Comment: I want more fine grain control on the client side. So if im doing $http calls from a service that should be pointing to multiple outside servers how would I point to different calls?